# Sending bulk notification, want to decide on scheduler time frequency

Tags: java, spring-boot

Sending bulk notification,
I'm developing a scheduler application for sending bulk notifications,

Since sending all the user based in one-shot is not a good practice I want to decide on scheduler time frequency  and number of users for per frequency for around 1 million users.

Example : every 1 minute sending message to 50 users.

Comment: Your question is not that clear. Try and make it more explicit.

Comment: If you are getting the the user token from database..... All you need do is query by limit say 500 tokens. Start a scheduler that gets called at a given time, query the tokens from db and keep pushing till you push to all users.

Comment: Don't forget to stop the thread when there's no more token fetched.